# Deny subscription to users with different domain on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, xmpp, chat, subscription

I'm developing an application on GAE (google app engine). This app is a chat bot which the users can use in order to access some resources. The problem is that I don't want that any user who knows the app ID can add that chatbot to their contacts because it manages private information, so I want to restrict the access only for my domain accounts. I read the GAE documentation and found this (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/overview#Handling_Subscriptions) but I don't really know how to apply it. I did something like this:

```
class SuscribeHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    sender = self.request.get('from').split('/')[0]
    domain = sender.split("@")[1]
    if domain == "mydomain.com":
      #Add contact code goes here


app = webapp.WSGIApplication([
  ('/_ah/xmpp/subscription/subscribe/', SuscribeHandler),
  ], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent a user from adding your bot to the roster. Per the XMPP docs:

> App Engine accepts all chat invitations and automatically registers subscriptions as described in the Handling Subscriptions section. App Engine routes all chat messages to the application, regardless of whether the sender previously sent an invitation to the app.

You should simply refuse to respond to messages that come from users not authorized to use your app.

Comment: Thank you very much Nick...is it safe if I just parse the sender email and check the domain? I mean...Can I receive spoofing identity attacks ?

Comment: @jtello To the best of my knowledge, XMPP guarantees the identity of senders - so you should be able to rely on the identity as specified.